# Different dpi per monitor windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have Lenovo thinkpad 15.6″ display with resolution: 1920x1080 and an extended display: ThinkVision: 19″ display with resolution: 1440x900. 
I need to set different dpi for both the monitors. Is this possible, if yes then how?

Answer (score 6):

No, not in Windows 7, DPI settings affect the entire desktop, regardless of number or arrangement of monitors.

First possible since Windows 8.1 due to [DPI scaling enhancements](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements/).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible using any software, if not the inbuilt settings?

Comment: Not to my knowledge ...

Answer (score 4):

There is workaround that will allow you to do something very similar to per-monitor DPI if you have a recent Nvidia GPU and drivers (9XX or higher).

1. Right click on your Desktop
2. Open the Nvidia control panel
3. Go to 3D settings
4. In the global tab, find "DSR - factors"
5. Select all options
6. Click apply
7. Go to the resolution settings, and set your smaller screen resolution to a resolution similar to the bigger screen. Preferably choose 2x resolution to minimize the blur of DSR.

While it's not most elegant solution, it works and is better than turning down the resolution of another screen.

**Troubleshooting:**

Sometimes DSR will not accept your native resolution. If that's the case, then do the following:

- Download [Custom Resolution Utility](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)
- Launch it
- Select the offending (smaller) display
- Remove all resolutions that are bigger than native. Watch for "extra" reported resolutions hidden under "Extension blocks".
- Edit your extension block (NOT REMOVE), and look for data blocks that state "X resolutions". Edit them and purge everything bigger than native.
- After saving the changes (pressing OK, so program quits) use "restart" and "restart64" to restart your graphic driver and make it register changes.
- Be aware, your screen will go black for a second and may go small res, don't worry and let it work.
- After applying this workaround to the bad DSR native resolutions, uncheck all the DSR's applied, and check them again (so the DSR resolutions will be reloaded/recreated).

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot verify as of now as I am not using win machine now.

Comment: Ive verified that as I was looking for an anwser for this question and it took me couple of days to figure out.

Comment: I don't get at all how this works. If I set the DSR resolution of the screen with the lowest native resolution to that of the one with the better native resolution (let's say, setting one FullHD monitor to a 4K resolution), everything looks, as expected, incredibly tiny (and blurred). This is not, per se, what the OP is asking for. If I then set Windows screen settings to a 200%, of course it will grow bigger but look horrible. In a 3 monitor setup, you end with 2 of 3 screens not at their native resolution... Am I missing some point here??

Comment: It works by using Nvidia to scale display instead of windows, and doing it "by reverse". As I said, it's far from elegant solution but only one that actually works. You are not missing point here, its solution that will allow you achieve same goal - of having same scaling of interface on each monitor.

Answer (score 1):

update for free to Windows 10 (till 29. July 2016) and [here you also have the option to manually change the DPI per Monitor](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2015/12/08/display-scaling-in-windows-10/) in the settings app.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this is office laptop and cannot upgrade to Win 10.

Comment: again,this is a NEW FEATURE since Windows 8.1, if you want to use it, update to Windows 10 (which also works for business devices), if you want to stay at Windows 7 you can't use it.